# how to call an ajax function with dynamic ID's- MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i try to update a DropDownList from selected item in another DropDownList . 
the page contain option to multiple DropDownList with the same data

```
@model List<CimenaCityProject.Models.TimeScreening>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
int? numberOfNewTimeScreening = ViewBag.number;
if (!numberOfNewTimeScreening.HasValue)
{
    numberOfNewTimeScreening = 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNewTimeScreening; i++)
{

}

var SelectMovieID = (SelectList)ViewBag.MovieID;
var SelectHomeCinemaID = (SelectList)ViewBag.HomeCinemaID;
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "TimeScreening", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>TimeScreening</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("ShowTime", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Theatres", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Date", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Price", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Is Displayed", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNewTimeScreening.Value; i++)
        {
            string HomeCinemaID = "["+i + "].MovieTheaters.HomeCinemaID".ToString();
            string TheatresID = "["+ i + "].TheatresID".ToString();   

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <br />
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].MovieShowTime.Single().MovieID, SelectMovieID, "Select Movie")
                        <br /><br />
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].MovieShowTimeID, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "--Loading Value--")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].MovieShowTimeID)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <br />
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].MovieTheaters.HomeCinemaID, SelectHomeCinemaID, "Select Home Cinema",
                 new { id = HomeCinemaID.ToString(), name = HomeCinemaID.ToString() })

                        <br /><br />

                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].TheatresID, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "--Loading Value--",
                        new {id=TheatresID.ToString(), name = TheatresID.ToString()})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].TheatresID)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Date)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Date)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Price)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Price)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].IsDisplayed)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].IsDisplayed)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
}
```

as you see the page get number and the for loop duplicate the data . 
when the for loop start he gave dynamic id for the dropdownlist

```
model[i].TheatresID
```

when the user select a HomeCinema ajax have to start and loading the Theatres that connect to the home Cinema .

the code here contain the founction for the HomeCinema and for the Movie . the last code is convert to JSON DATETIME.

Ajax CODE :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //function for HomeCinema. 
    $(function () {
        $('@HomeCinemaID.ToString()').change(function () {
            alert("ok1")
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetTheatres","TimeScreening")',
                data: { CinemaID: $('@HomeCinemaID.ToString()').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(@TheatresID.ToString()).html('');
                    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                        $(@TheatresID.ToString()).append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownEror) {
                    alert("Error by loading the Theatres");
                }
            });
        });
   });


    $(function () {
        $('#'+j + '.MovieID').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetShowTime", "TimeScreening")',
                data: { MovieID: $('#' + j + '.MovieID').val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#' + j + '.MovieShowTimeID').html('');
                    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                        var name = DatetimeConverter(option.name)
                        $('#' + j + '.MovieShowTimeID').append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(name));
                    });

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownEror) {
                    alert("False" + xhr + "..." + ajaxOptions + "... " + thrownEror);
                }
            });
        });
    });


// START Datetime Converters
function DateConverter(date) {
    var aux = null;
    if (date != null) {
        aux = date.substring(6);
        aux = aux.substring(0, aux.indexOf(')'));
    }

    return aux != null ? getISODate(new Date(parseInt(aux))) : "";
}

function DatetimeConverter(date) {
    var aux = null;
    if (date != null) {
        aux = date.substring(6);
        aux = aux.substring(0, aux.indexOf(')'));
    }
    return aux != null ? getISODateTime(new Date(parseInt(aux))) : "";
}

function getISODate(d) {
    // padding function
    var s = function (a, b) { return (1e15 + a + "").slice(-b) };

    // default date parameter
    if (typeof d === 'undefined') {
        d = new Date();
    };

    // return ISO datetime
    return zeroPad(d.getDate(), 2) + '/' +
    zeroPad(s(d.getMonth() + 1, 2), 2) + '/' +
    zeroPad(d.getFullYear(), 4);
}

function getISODateTime(d) {
    // padding function
    var s = function (a, b) { return (1e15 + a + "").slice(-b) };

    // default date parameter
    if (typeof d === 'undefined') {
        d = new Date();
    };

    // return ISO datetime
    return zeroPad(d.getHours(), 2) + ":" +
    zeroPad(d.getMinutes(), 2) + ":" +
    zeroPad(d.getSeconds(), 2);
}

function zeroPad(num, places) {
    var zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
    return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + num;
}
// END Datetime Converters


</script>
    }
    }
```

code :

```
        public ActionResult GetTheatres(int? CinemaID)
    {
        var data = (from d in db.Theaters
                    where d.HomeCinemaID == CinemaID
                    select new
                    {
                        id = d.MovieTheatersID,
                        name = d.TheatersName
                    }).ToList();

        return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetShowTime(int? MovieID)
    {

        var data = (from m in db.MovieShowTimes
                    where m.MovieID == MovieID
                    select new
                    {
                        id = m.MovieShowTimeID,
                        name = m.ShowTime
                    }).ToList();

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

after this the controller get the list that user make and add to db.

Controller:

```
    // POST: /TimeScreening/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TimeScreeningID,MovieShowTimeID,TheatresID,Date,Price,IsDisplayed")] List<TimeScreening> Timescreening)
    {
        int check = 0;
        foreach (var timescreening in Timescreening)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.TimeScreening.Add(timescreening);
                check = db.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
        if (check== 1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View("Create", Timescreening);



    }
```

when i work with one element (no for loop and static id) this work perfect 
how i can make it work with multiple and dynamic id's?

Answer (score 0):

Ziv, instead of attaching your change event handler to an ID selector, do it with a class instead. And for every dropdown you want the event to be handled the way you coded, add this specific class.

Don't define an ID element in your dropdowns at all.

Example:

```
<select class='myDropDown' ...>

</select>

<select class='myDropDown' ...>
</select>

**jquery**:
$(".myDropDown").change(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: for this:@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].MovieTheaters.HomeCinemaID, SelectHomeCinemaID, "Select Home Cinema",new { @class = HomeCinemaID})
 I get this:       <select class="[0].HomeCinemaID" data-val="true" name="[0].MovieTheaters.HomeCinemaID"><option value="">Select Home Cinema</option>
<option value="1">obs</option>
</select>
and this still not work.. 
$(function () {
        $('#[0].HomeCinemaID').change(function () {
            alert("ok")
        });
       });

Comment: replace "model => model[i].MovieTheaters.HomeCinemaID" with "model => int.Parse(model[i].MovieTheaters.HomeCinemaID)"

Comment: you sure? if the normal result is [0].HomeCinemaID so it cant be parsing this string..
EDIT : this throw exeption : Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: I am not, because your problem is not very clear. In any case, you wrote above: and this still not work.. $(function () { $('#[0].HomeCinemaID').change(function () { alert("ok") }); }) -> this is indeed an invalid selector. What change event you want to handle ?

Comment: i try to update the dropdownlist "TheatresID" , when user select element from HomeCinema DropDownlist the code : $(function () { $('#[0].HomeCinemaID').change(function () { alert("ok") }); }); is just to try enter the script place see if the basic work. but as you see even the option for select element and send it to script alert "ok" this dont work.
what i need to do?

Comment: What I am saying is that I do not think "#[0].HomeCinemaId" is a valid selector. Can you run the following ->  $("#[0].HomeCinemaId") <- in your chrome's console and see if you get any results ?